# Can't get the value of HTML select in AJAX response

Tags: javascript, ajax

There are two steps on my code. First step a user fills some fields and then data is submitted by ajax to server. Ajax returns a HTML select input that user must choose a value. This is the second step.

The problem is, when I try to get the value of select in javascript, it shows me null.

The code I use to get select value works in normal situation. But when select is retrieved by ajax, this problem occurs.

Code to get select value

```
var e = document.getElementById("ordernum");
var num = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Comment: post the full code with the ajax, how you're appending it to the dom

Comment: `The problem is, when I try to get the value of select in javascript, it shows me null.` <-- Which leads me to believe that you're trying to access the value before it is actually compiled (it's asyncronous). Post the full code please

Comment: Guys there is no problem with ajax. It returns some HTML code including a select, as it should be. The returned HTML will be put in some div with innerHTML function (Here is when select appears). Whole code is complex but if you think it could help, I'll post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example HTML file showing how to dynamically generate a select element and get the value back from it on its onchange event via event.target.value:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script>
            const GameDifficulty = {
                EASY:1,
                MEDIUM:2,
                HARD:3,
                INSANE:4
            };

            function init(event) {
                console.log(event);
                var body = document.getElementById('body');
                var select = document.createElement('select');
                select.id = 'selDifficulty';
                for (var diff in GameDifficulty) {
                    var option = document.createElement('option');
                    option.value = GameDifficulty[diff];
                    option.innerHTML = diff;
                    select.appendChild(option);
                }

                select.onchange = test;

                body.appendChild(select);
                console.log(body);
            }

            function test(event) {
                console.log(event.target.value);
            }

            window.onload = init;
        </script>
    </head>
    <body id="body">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I edited the code. Did't work. The code I wrote in post is the code that I always use to get a select option value in JS. And it works all time except this time.

Comment: You can get individual options using that code, yes, but it's not the right way to get access to the value of the select for a form submission. You need to get the value from the select itself rather than the options values.

Comment: I don't want to submit a form in second step. I just want to get the value that user is selected.

Comment: And this is how it's done. I'll add some example code to illustrate.

Comment: Thank you man. Yes I know it works in normal situation. My code also works. But when select is in ajax response code, it shows null. Select is not in page when page is loaded. It will be added by ajax later when user submits information in first step.

Comment: It would be best in that instance then, if you supply code in the body of your question in order to replicate the issue with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I'll try to replicate the issue in the meantime.

Comment: I've amended my answer to reflect your new requirements. See if this works for you and gives you what you need :)

Comment: I could solve the problem by using your test function. Thank you man!